# How to quickly and efficiently test project on Tomcat local server after making changes

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm trying to build a Dynamic Web Application in Eclipse and I'm having trouble when I test my changes.

Sometimes when I make changes, I relaunch the Tomcat server and behold, my project looks exactly the same as last time. I then clean and rebuild the project a few times as well as clean the server, and finally my changes are visible.

This is time consuming and doesn't feel correct.

Is there a proper, quicker, more efficient way to launch a clean copy of your project on the local server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that selecting `Build Automatically`, under the `Projects` menu item, changes in the code are automatically recompiled and added to the currently running Tomcat server instance.

Now it's going great! Much faster!

Answer (score 3):

I have used the Eclipse Tomcat plugin for years with no issues and more recently the Spring Tools Suite with plugin for their customized Tomcat. As you say having your project Build Automatically and having the Server configuration, via the plugin, set to Publish Changes Automatically goes some way towards alleviating the pain of Java web development.

For non Java files (JSP, CSS, JSF, JS etc.) you should see the changes instantly. For Java files, the plugin will reload the application to reflect the changed classes. While this works okay for small applications, for large applications the reload time can become significant. There can also be issues with permgen after multiple reloads and you can lose your session and be booted back to some previous screen and have to step back through the various screens  to see your changes.

The ultimate solution then is to use a tool called JRebel which will swap you updated classes into the running VM without the requirement to reload the whole application as well as publishing non java files, reloading application config files (log4J, Spring) managing JPA entities and a lot more.

http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/

It's a commercial product and while not exactly cheap, in my experience worth every penny. I've been using it for years and couldn't live without it. Your productivity will increase x-fold especially when working on larger applications. No connection, just a satisfied customer.

For a free alternative see:

http://www.hotswapagent.org

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Good to know about. I had only heard of JRebel, but not exactly what it does

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the tomcat plugin in eclipse has been flaky like this from the beginning. I suggest that you not use it - its just not worth the trouble.

There are at least two alternatives.
First, you could just install tomcat locally, build your war file, and deploy it manually.

A better alternative IMHO is to set up a maven build for your project, and then install the maven tomcat plugin, which just works. I've never seen it get flaky.

Something similar is probably available for gradle, if you want to use that instead of maven.

Comment: Link to Maven Tomcat plugin you are referring to?